# Search array by key branch

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = array (
    [level_1] => array (
        [level_2] => array (
            [level_3] => something
        )
    ),
    [level_12] => array (
        [level_2] => somethingelse
    ),
    [level_13] => array (
        [level_22] => array (
            [level_3] => something
        )
    ),
);
```

The keys or values aren't always unique but the branches are.
And I have a string that looks like this:

```
$string = 'level_1-level_2-level_3';
```

Those are the keys for a branch.

And I need to somehow get the value from the array based on that string?
Like this:

```
$string_array = explode('-', $string);
$array[$string_array[0]][$string_array[1]][$string_array[2]] // something
```

But since the depth can be different this is not a viable solution...

Comment: You need to create a recursive function, what collects the results.

Comment: Just create a variable called $result, make it equal $array, then run a loop on your $string_array making $result = $result[$string_array[$i]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple example, no need for a recursive function:

```
function get_item( $path, $array ) 
{
    $paths = explode( '-', $path );

    $result = $array;       
    foreach ( $paths as $path) {
        isset( $result[$path] ) ? $result = $result[$path] : $result = false;
    }

    return $result; 
}

$path = 'level_1-level_2-level_3';
echo get_item( $path, $array );
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a break in the loop if result is false? Or is it okay to treat a boolean as an array?

Comment: I suppose it should, but PHP does not throw any warnings or notices 
when using `isset()` that way

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $array = array (
    'level_1' => array (
        'level_2' => array (
            'level_3' => 'something'
        )
    ),
    'level_12' => array (
        'level_2' => 'somethingelse'
    ),
    'level_13' => array (
        'level_22' => array (
            'level_3' => 'something'
        )
    ),
);
$string = 'level_1-level_2-level_3';
$keys = explode('-', $string);

echo getItemIterative($keys, $array);
echo "\n";
echo getItemRecursive($keys, $array);


function getItemIterative($keys, $array)
{
    $value = null;
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if ($value == null) {
            $value = $array[$key];
        }
        if (is_array($value) && array_key_exists($key, $value)) {
            $value = $value[$key];
        }
    }
    return $value;
}

function getItemRecursive($keys, $array)
{
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    $value = $array[$key];
    if (empty($keys)) {
        return $value;
    } else {
        return getItemRecursive($keys, $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `$result` variable which initially points to the root of the array, and loop through the levels of your `$string_array` 'til `$result` points at the leaf you were looking for.

```
// stuff you already have:

$array = array(...); // your big array
$string = 'level_1-level_2-level_3';
$string_array = explode('-', $string);

// new stuff:

$result = $array;
foreach ($string_array as $level) {
    $result = $result[$level];
}

echo $result; // 'something'
```

Working example: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/STmqSk)

Comment: It will work fine if `$string` is ok, but it will throw undefined index error if is not.